# What firebase version can I install for Xcode 9.4.1

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I just recently upgraded to Xcode 9.4.1 and wanted to make use of firebase for the first time. I learnt how to use Cocoa-Pods to install firebase. I got errors, then I found out that the current version of firebase only supports Xcode 10.1 and above. And I can't upgrade to Xcode 10.1.

The problem now is what version of firebase can I install for Xcode 9.4.1 and also how to install it.  And also are there alternatives to firebase?

Comment: Look for the one compatible with you: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#6.13.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find from here that which firebase version usable from which xcode version;

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_5160_-_january_22_2019

You can use 5.16.0 version on Xcode 9.4.1

Comment: Thanks ! How do i use coco pods to download it though ?